# Setting a TextFilter's value from a Query String (URL) Filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to start off by saying I'm very new to Sharepoint, so I'm sorry if I'm asking something very obvious.  I've done quite a bit a googling and can't find an answer to my question.  This leads me to believe that maybe I'm asking the wrong question.  So, here goes:

We have a Sharepoint webpage that currently contains 3 Web Parts (2 lists and a text filter).  The text filter can be used to filter the two lists.  I've been asked to provide the following functionality:

1. A user must be able to open this page from an http link (easy)
2. The Text-Filter must be automatically filled-in and applied, thus immediately filtering the two lists

This seemed pretty straight-forward to me:  Pull a parameter from the page's URL and feed it into the filter.
I found and added a Query String (URL) Filter and I managed to pull the parameter from the URL, but I can't feed it to the existing Filter!

Sure, I can pass the value to the two lists (effectively coding the same filter two different ways) but that seems wrong.  So, my question boils down to this:

Is it possible to set a Text Filter's value from a Query String (URL) Filer?

Am I asking the wrong question?  Am I looking at this problem in the wrong way?  Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *was* asking the wrong question!

It seems you can set a Text Filter's value on page-load through the URL.  Here's how:

```
http://sharepoint-server/site/subsite/project/default.aspx?Text%20Filter%20Name=999
```

Where **Text%20Filter%20Name** is the name of your Text Filer (in this case, with spaces in the name), and where **999** is the value you're passing to the filter.